# Using VIEWs in PostGres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to write an SQL query for a PostGres database. The goal is to create a view based on the contents of a table.

This is my starting table:

```
Rank  Value
 1      4
 2      5
 3      8
 4      11
 5      19
 6      32
 7      55
```

This is the view I would like to build:

```
Rank  Value  SumUpTo
 1      4       4
 2      5       9
 3      8       17
 4      11      28
 5      19      47
 6      32      79
 7      55      134
```

The columns Rank and Value are just copied from the original table.
The column SumUpTo is computed by adding all the values in the original table from rank 1 up to the current rank.

I have tried these kind of queries, among others, but it all failed:

```
CREATE VIEW myview AS SELECT rank,value,(SELECT SUM(value) FROM mytable WHERE (rank<rank)) as SumUpTo FROM mytable;
CREATE VIEW myview AS SELECT rank,value,(SELECT SUM(value) FROM mytable WHERE (rank<mytable.rank)) as SumUpTo FROM mytable;
```

What is the correct way to write the query to get the result I want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sum` analytic function:

```
SQL> select rank, value,
  2    sum(value) over (order by rank) sumUpTo
  3  from test
  4  order by rank;

      RANK      VALUE    SUMUPTO
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          4          4
         2          5          9
         3          8         17

SQL>
```

Add `create view` yourself; see the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RhQ4tRLf), if you want.